# Printing all kernel revisions where the patch is backported

Tags: git, github, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a commit id of patch fix for a latest kernel. I want to know all the kernel revisions where that patch is backported. Currently I use `git describe --contains commitid` which gives me only one result which I am not sure is the right one. Is there any other command or a way to modify this command to list all the previous revisions where the patch was applied? I have cloned the stable kernel repository.

Most of the backported commit message will be like `commit commitid upstream`. So can we like write a script or so to check these types of commit messages?

Comment: Be aware, that the same commit (the ID and the contents) may have been changed in stable trees. So, roughly your command is correct. The rest is a set of special cases.

Comment: @0andriy Yes but how do I list all revisions

Comment: Automatically?! No way. What you may try to do is to checkout each tag and try to cherry-pick the commit. If it does not fail, there is **possibly** (e.g. it was there and had been reverted) no such commit, if it fails, **probably** it is there. But as far you from origin (of the commit) the harder this task to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct. But as @0andriy has also told that Commit ID may also changed (because every time you applied same patch it will generate the different commit ID). But **commit message** most of the time  remain same. So you can verify it through **git log -p** or **git log --oneline** command.

Comment: I don't want to go and see all commit messages. This is not correct answer